# Stop tomcat writing to stdout and stderror

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, docker, fluentd

We use docker. We use fluentd as our logging driver for our docker containers. We use tomcat to serve java applications. When there is an exception thrown in a java application we use a log4j to handle that exception. To control the logging I have installed log4j in tomcat according to the instructions https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html on that page. Here is the configuration I am using.

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CATALINA

# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = stewart %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/manager
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

# log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
# log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] = INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] = INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

The issue is for each error that gets logged the stack trace still gets written out to stderr. This causes our logging platform to have log messages written to it twice. What is the best way to stop all stack traces being written to stderr?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of "many errors"?

Comment: @Stewart, do you have stderr as an appender somewhere in your log4j configuration? I think it would be useful to provide the configuration, at least its essential part with appenders and logs.

Comment: @Stewart - :) , so I think your log4j configuration is incomplete. Can you show that as well please?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to suppress the error output.

```
 System.setErr(null);
```

I'm using spring and I got this code to run at startup by using the PostConstruct annotation.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SurpressLogging {

    @PostConstruct
    public void err() {
        System.setErr(null);
    }
}
```